# Browser Support for HTML5 full-screen API

Tags: html, fullscreen

Can anyone tell me how well is the HTML5 full-screen API supported in major browser? Specifically, the lowest version of each browser which supports it full-fledged? For those who don't (I strongly suspect IE is one), are there any 3rd party libraries which may help in standardizing it for that browser version?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Comment: I don't think it is correct, it says Firefox version 16 onwards, whereas it's working fine for my version 5...

Comment: It doesn't say that 5 *didn't* support it. It says nothing about version 5.

Comment: It starts from version 16 there, so doesn't that mean that it suggests version 16 is the lowest version supporting it?

Comment: No, it means it doesn't have/display data for anything below 16. "Not supported" is red, not listed is "not listed". Mozilla itself says 9.0/10.0: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FUsing_full-screen_mode

Comment: Then how can I go by this site when I see it works for FF 5, Mozilla says FF 9, but it says 16?

Comment: Maybe you should clarify why the specific version number is so important to you in the first place. Are you trying *browser detection* instead of *feature detection*?

Comment: Not exactly. I am just planning to develop a full-screen API for an app. For that I need to know which browser's lowest version support it, so that, combined with our demographics stats, we can decide whether to go for it or not. A discrepancy between version 5.1 and 5.3 is acceptable, but here they are saying version 16, or 11 (as per the link in the answer below), whereas I am clearly seeing that version 5 supports it..

Answer (score 1):

This will answer your question: http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/fullscreen

Browser/Device           Market Share   HTML5 Video     Flash Video
Chrome                   30%                Yes     Yes
Firefox              19%                Yes     Yes
Internet Explorer 9      16%                Yes     Yes
Internet Explorer 6/7/8  13%                 No     Yes
Safari                4%                Yes     Yes
Opera                     1%                Yes     Yes
iOS                       5%                Yes     No
Android               4%                Yes     No
Other (feature phones)    8%                 No     No

Current spec: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html

Comment: Exactly. My FF 5 clearly supports it, but they are saying version 11. I want to know the lowest working version..

Answer (score 1):

Best website for checking browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen